# NLogConfigurationException - Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Uri'

Tags: asp.net, nlog, nlog-configuration

Nlog is throwing an exception now that I have updated from 1.0 -> 2.0.

When NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.Initialize is called the following exception occurs:

**"Error when setting property 'Url' on WebService Target[Target_AuditLog_WebService_Global]"**

with an innerException of:
 **"Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Uri'.**

the target looks like this:

```
<target name="Target_AuditLog_WebService_Global" xsi:type="WebService" namespace="http://ourLoggingServer.corp/" protocol="Soap12" methodName="AddLog" url="http://ourLoggingServer.corp/Logger.asmx">
  <parameter /> <!-- Several params, none of type system.uri -->
</target>
```

I found this however it seems they think its fixed:
http://nlog.codeplex.com/workitem/5352

Comment: Yes, it happens you to try to cast a string that is a relative link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug and has been fixed, however, a version with the fix has not yet been released officially or via NuGet, if you run across this issue you will need to use a nightly build version: 
http://nlog.codeplex.com/releases/view/64708 (which I have confirmed works) 
If there has been an official release after 4/27/2011 you should try using it.

http://nlog.codeplex.com/releases